# will GRUB destroy the access to the lenovo recovery system=?

Tags: grub2, lenovo

I wonder if I install Ubuntu on a lenovo Y700 -15ISK, will I still be able to boot into the recovery mode setup by lenovo?

Thanks

Comment: I believe when you say recovery mode setup...you are talking about Windows7/8.1/10 recovery mode, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to access it. See screenshot [image]